# How to access files on a guest OS from a host OS in VMWare?

Tags: windows-7, vmware-workstation

It's easy to share a folder which resides on the host file system with the guest OS, but is it possible to do the reverse?
i.e. is it possible to share a *guest* directory with the host OS, so that the file stays on the guest's file system?

My guest is Linux and my host is Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is - but it all depends on your networking setup. What I do to make this super easy is ensure the guest uses bridged networking. That way the virtual NIC will get an IP that is on the same subnet as the host - for example:

HOST: 192.168.1.5 / 255.255.255.0 (assigned by DHCP)
Guest: 192.168.1.6 / 255.255.255.0 (assigned by DHCP)

This way you can always ping the Guest and have a whatever access to files you setup.

Here is an article on how to share a folder on Linux so Windows can access it:
[Share Linux folder with Windows](http://microdevsys.com/wp/networking-sharing-folders-between-windows-and-linux-using-samba/2/)